# copy_from_user warning on size not being provably correct?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, procfs

I encountered a warning produced when compiling my kernel module that I can't get to work around.

First take a look at this simplified code:

```
#define READ_CHUNK 100u
static int _procfs_write(struct file *file, const char *buf, unsigned long count, void *data)
{
    char command[READ_CHUNK];
    unsigned long left = count;
    while (left > 0)
    {
        unsigned int amount = left<READ_CHUNK?left:READ_CHUNK;    
        if (copy_from_user(command, buf, amount))
            return -EFAULT;
        buf += amount;
        left -= amount;
        /* process buffer */
    }
    return count;
}
```

The warning I get is the following:

> warning: call to ‘copy_from_user_overflow’ declared with attribute warning: copy_from_user() buffer size is not provably correct

As you can see, this is completely wrong. `amount` of data that I read is provably fine! I found [this link](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/hid-picolcd-avoid-compile-warning-error-triggered-by-copy-user-help-203196072.html) saying `min` can be used in the last parameter to silence gcc, but it didn't work for me (I wrote:

```
if (copy_from_user(command, buf, min((unsigned long)amount, count)))
```

to no avail).

**Does anyone know how to let gcc know that this is cool and it shouldn't worry?**

---

Another place where this happens is something like the following:

```
static int _procfs_write(struct file *file, const char *buf, unsigned long count, void *data)
{
    char *read_buffer = vmalloc(count * sizeof(*read_buffer));
    if (read_buffer == NULL)
        return -ENOMEM;
    if (copy_from_user(read_buffer, buf, count))
    {
        vfree(read_buffer);
        return -EFAULT;
    }
    /* process buffer */
    vfree(read_buffer);
    return count;
}
```

In this case also gcc gives me the same warning, even though it is surely correct.

---

This is the exact error:

```
In file included from /usr/src/linux-2.6.35.9-rtai-9jan2012/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h:571:0,
                 from <my source file>:7:
/usr/src/linux-2.6.35.9-rtai-9jan2012/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess_32.h: In function ‘copy_from_user’:
/usr/src/linux-2.6.35.9-rtai-9jan2012/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess_32.h:212:26: warning: call to ‘copy_from_user_overflow’ declared with attribute warning: copy_from_user() buffer size is not provably correct
```

Kernel version: 2.6.35.9 patched with rtai (as you can see)

Comment: Can you also tell us which file this warning is thrown? What is your kernel version and other such details?

Comment: @PavanManjunath, I'm at home now, but I'll get back to you tomorrow morning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, try replacing

```
min((unsigned long)amount, count)
```

with

```
min((unsigned long)READ_CHUNK, count)
```

Now, it can be proved that copy size will not exceed 100 bytes at *compile time itself* and hence convince gcc that we will never overwrite the destination buffer `command` which is also 100 bytes.

In your second example, neither `read_buffer` nor `count` are known at compile time. If you don't want this error to bog you, you *need to* send **compile time evaluable parameters** ( destination buffer and copy size ) to `copy_from_user`

If you check the mainlined linux kernel, you will hardly find examples where they are writing user space data into into a malloced buffer inside the kernel. So I guess, if your code has to be perfectly safe, you need to do away the mallocing of the buffer

**PS**: Read about how gcc  implements a limited [buffer overflow protection](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Object-Size-Checking.html) mechanism that can prevent some buffer overflow attacks.

Comment: Although it should be `min((unsigned long)READ_CHUNK, amount)`, because `amount` is what I need to read, but still this doesn't solve the problem with the second case where the memory is dynamically allocated and thus a fixed size such as `READ_CHUNK` doesn't exist!

Comment: By the way, I tried what you said (min og READ_CHUCK and amount), and I still get the same warning

Comment: Does the warning go away if you hard code the copy size? Say something like 50(<100)

Comment: This indeed is strange! I used copy size of `READ_CHUNK` and even a plane `5` and it still gives me the same warning. I have only one `copy_from_user`, so it can't be somewhere else.

Comment: Well no actually, it went away with optimization on etc