# How to get rid of warning when copy_to_user(struct *file, const char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *off_t )

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

This is my myread and mywrite function of the null driver.

```
#define SIZE 6
    static char c[SIZE];

    static ssize_t myread(struct file *file,char __user *buf,size_t len, loff_t  *fops)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO"My read with length %zd \n",len);

    memset(buf,0,SIZE);
    //return is status i.e., 0.
    if(copy_to_user(buf,c,SIZE) != 0)
        return -EFAULT;
    else if (*fops > 0)
        return 0;
        else
            *fops += SIZE;
            return SIZE;
}


static ssize_t mywrite(struct file *file, const char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *fops)
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "My write \n");
        memset(c,0,SIZE);
            if (len <= SIZE)`
            {`
        if(copy_from_user(c,buf,len) != 0)
            return -EFAULT;
        else
            //number of bytes written to the kernel space is returned
            return len;`
            }
            else 
                    return -EFAULT;`
    }
```

When i build the module it is throwing warning like this:

> /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-36-generic-pae/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess_32.h: In function ‘mywrite’:
>   /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-36-generic-pae/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess_32.h:211:26: warning: call to ‘copy_from_user_overflow’ declared with attribute warning: copy_from_user() buffer size is not provably correct [enabled by default]

please guide me like how to get rid of this warning. Like where am i doing mistake..

Comment: Warnings in kernel code have to investigated, not just silenced. It seems that it is complaining about the buffer and its size in your code, check that you can write at the address given and that the size fits.

Comment: @vonbrand Yes i could see the problem is likely to be with buffer and size. But I am properly doing memset in my write function. Otherwise I am not using buf or 'c array' anywhere except copy_from_user. I couldn figure out the problem with warning.

Comment: 1) what is "c" in `strlen(c);`?  (OOPS a static ... brrr) 2) dont printf a size_t with a "%d" format. 3) what is wrong with `sizeof c` instead of SIZE ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993929/copy-from-user-warning-on-size-not-being-provably-correct

Comment: @wildplasser 1: I have edited the code in question as you have said. getting the warning. 2: I have made %d as %zd. Again getting the warning

Comment: @clintp I see that link is not addressing the problem.

Comment: I disagree.  The compiler can't tell at *compile time* that you've got enough space for this data, and it needs to be sure.  Try compiling it with constants for your buffer declarations and length instead and see what happens.

Comment: @clintp Don't know how compiler is that intelligent to tell but inserting a check for len with SIZE has removed the warning. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the `len` passed in to your `myread` and `mywrite` functions may be greater than `SIZE`; if this is the case, the `copy_from_user`/`copy_to_user` will overflow your array and read from / write to other nearby memory. Your code needs to restrict the length of the copy to no more than the length of the kernel memory that it's accessing.

Comment: Yes the warning is with copy_from_user. I have done with modifications to the mywrite as well myread code. With this I am getting warning again.

Comment: Passing `SIZE` isn't correct either, because it may be larger than the requested `len`. You will need to specifically check the passed `len` and limit it to no more than `SIZE`.

Comment: yes you are right. I inserted a check there. warning went thanks.